# Python numpy linspace for small numbers

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a little problem with linspace. I would like to generate an array of numbers like:

`[0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001 , 0.001 ,0 .01 , 0.1]`

so I've tried following code:

```
alphas = np.linspace(0.0000001,10,num=11)
print(alphas)
```

and got result:

```
[  1.00000000e-07   1.00000009e+00   2.00000008e+00   3.00000007e+00
4.00000006e+00   5.00000005e+00   6.00000004e+00   7.00000003e+00
8.00000002e+00   9.00000001e+00   1.00000000e+01]
```

than i thought that it must be problem with display and format but after trying

```
if(alphas[0]>1):
    print("yes the first number is greater than 1")
if(alphas[1]>1):
    print("yes the second number is greater than 1")
```

the second number is really greater than one

so my question is what's wrong? since linspace should "Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval."

Answer (score 5):

It's doing what you are asking: Creating a linearly increasing set of numbers between 1e-7 and 10. Since this is almost the same as the range 0 to 10, then it's not surprising that you get an increment of one.

What you want in your case is [`np.logspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) which gives you a logarithmic increase instead:

```
In [2]: np.logspace(-7, 1, num=11)
Out[2]: 
array([  1.00000000e-07,   6.30957344e-07,   3.98107171e-06,
         2.51188643e-05,   1.58489319e-04,   1.00000000e-03,
         6.30957344e-03,   3.98107171e-02,   2.51188643e-01,
         1.58489319e+00,   1.00000000e+01])
```

As pointed out by Warren Weckesser, as of NumPy 1.12 there is also the [`np.geomspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html) function that is slightly easier to use, as you can give it the endpoints directly, instead of its power-of-ten exponent:

`np.geomspace(1e-7, 10, num=11)`

Comment: *"What you want in your case is np.logspace ..."* or, if you are using a recent version of numpy, [geomspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Ah, sweet, I had missed that. Very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

You could just take the 10-power, if you want the series to be like you show. If you want even spacing in log-space, go for Hannes Ovrén's answer.

```
alpha = 10.**np.arange(-7, 2)
```

Printing `alpha` gives:

```
Out[1]: 
array([  1.00000000e-07,   1.00000000e-06,   1.00000000e-05,
         1.00000000e-04,   1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-02,
         1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use a list comprehension :

```
>>> a=[10.0**i for i in range(-7,-0)]
>>> a
[1e-07, 1e-06, 1e-05, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]
```

Comment: Or `10**np.arange(-7,0)`